# MySQL least privileges to get database/tables size

Tags: mysql, monitoring, nagios, mariadb, centreon

I'm using centreon_plugins to monitor some mysql databases. As a best practice I create a dedicated user for monitoring and I give it the least possible privileges.

For simple monitoring I usually create a monitor user with only 2 global privileges:

```
mysql> create user 'monitor'@'%' identified by 'monitorpassword';
mysql> grant SHOW DATABASES, REPLICATION CLIENT on *.* to 'monitor'@'%';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Now I'm required to check database size. To access DB size I need that the user monitor can access information_schema.tables, but I cannot give it direct select privileges to that table.

Obviously the root user I'm using has the GRANT privilege.

```
mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant SELECT on information_schema.tables to 'monitor'@'%';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

The access denied is due to the particular use that mysql reserves to the information_schema DB; the access to that DB is limited by the granted access to all other mysql objects.
I could achive the result giving the SELECT privilege on *.* to monitor user, but I don't want to do that because the monitor user is not protected enough (i.e. it's password is stored in cleartext in the monitoring software) and so it must not be able to see application data.

I tried various combination of privileges on different DBs and tables and none of them works.
(ref. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

Did someone had the same need? How did he/she resolved it?

For completeness, the queries executed by the monitoring plugin are:

```
show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table'
SELECT table_schema, table_name, engine, data_free, data_length+index_length as data_used, (DATA_FREE / (DATA_LENGTH+INDEX_LENGTH)) as TAUX_FRAG FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND engine IN ('InnoDB', 'MyISAM')
```

Thanks in advance.
Flavio

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for this kind of MySQL question.

Comment: I didn't see there was that site too.... I posted the same question even there, in the hope to find an answer... I don't really want to give select permission on everything. Too weird. Thanks for information.